# Custom UIViewController animation issue

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiviewcontroller

I created a simple custom transition animation for `UIViewController` with `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. Everything is working, but when target view presents, content starts appear from bottom right corner and when view is disappear, content disappear from left top corner. I attached gif with example. This is my code:

**CustomViewAnimator.swift**

```
class CustomViewAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    private let interval = 0.5
    var forward = false
    var originFrame: CGRect = .zero

    func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
        return interval
    }

    func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

        let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

        guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else {return}
        guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from) else {return}
        let destinationView = forward ? toView : fromView
        destinationView.alpha = forward ? 0 : 1

        forward ? containerView.addSubview(toView) : containerView.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)
        forward ? (destinationView.frame = originFrame) : (destinationView.frame = fromView.frame)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, animations: {

            self.forward ? (destinationView.frame = fromView.frame) : (destinationView.frame = self.originFrame)
            destinationView.alpha = self.forward ? 1 : 0

        }) { (finished) in
            transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
        }

    }

}
```

**MainViewController.self**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {

    private var button: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }

    @objc private func openView() {
        let viewController = TargetViewController()
        viewController.transitioningDelegate = self
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

    }
}

extension MainViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, animationControllerFor operation: UINavigationController.Operation, from fromVC: UIViewController, to toVC: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {

        let animator = CustomViewAnimator()
        animator.originFrame = button.frame
        animator.forward = (operation == .push)
        return animator
    }
}

extension MainViewController: UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate {
    func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        let animator = CustomViewAnimator()
        animator.forward = true
        return animator
    }

    func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
        let animator = CustomViewAnimator()
        animator.forward = false
        return animator
    }
}
```

**TargetViewController.swift**

```
class TargetViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setup()
    }

}

extension TargetViewController {

    fileprivate func setup() {
        view.backgroundColor = .orange
        navigationItem.title = "Target view"

        let label: UILabel = {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            label.text = "Hello from target view :)"
            label.textColor = .white
            label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18)
            return label
        }()
        view.addSubview(label)

        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Can anybody say how I can fix this issue, so label(or any other content) in TargetViewController stayed fixed on their places?

[image]

Comment: Can you show TargetViewController and especially it's constraints for label?

Comment: @PeterTretyakov I edited my post with adding TargetViewController

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your problem is because of mixing Auto Layout and frames. You position subviews (button and label) in `ViewController`s' views with constraints but for animation you use frames updates. So as I understand correctly how layout works your label constraints are not active during transition or at least are not used by layout engine to calculate position of label.

So, the best advice is to avoid frame animation in transition and try to create appropriate constraints for `.from` and `.to` views and animate constraints' constants. It would take more code, but you can be sure that you don't mix two different strategies for layout.

Easier solution is to tell `containerView` to calculate constraints and to position elements appropriately during animation by simply add `containerView.layoutIfNeeded()` to animations block. So it would be:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, animations: {
    self.forward ? (destinationView.frame = fromView.frame) : (destinationView.frame = self.originFrame)
    destinationView.alpha = self.forward ? 1 : 0
    containerView.layoutIfNeeded()
}) { (finished) in
    transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
}
```

But that only makes things work and doesn't solve the main problem with simultaneous usage of two layout strategies.

Comment: yes, I found about this in another resource. I fixed it with using CABasicAnimation instead of UIView.animation

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the discussion from other answers. My suggestion is instead of animating the frame of UIView, you may animate the mask of the destination View as following. It should be the effect of what the oper really wants.

**The bold part is the difference from the original post.**

```
 func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {

    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView

    guard let toView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .to) else {return}
    guard let fromView = transitionContext.view(forKey: .from) else {return}
    let destinationView = forward ? toView : fromView
    destinationView.alpha = forward ? 0 : 1
```

### let maskView = UIView.init(frame: forward ? originFrame : fromView.frame)

### maskView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

### destinationView.mask = maskView

```
    forward ? containerView.addSubview(toView) : containerView.insertSubview(toView, belowSubview: fromView)
    forward ? (destinationView.frame = toView.frame) : (destinationView.frame = fromView.frame)


    UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, animations: {
```

### self.forward ? (destinationView.mask?.frame = fromView.frame) : (destinationView.mask?.frame = self.originFrame)

```
        destinationView.alpha = self.forward ? 1 : 0
            }) { (finished) in

        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }

}
```